# Wordpress query_posts adding two "post-entry" divs, one with "post-thumbnail" and one without

Tags: wordpress, loops, thumbnails, wordpress-theming

Hi my name is Antony and this is my first question. I'm currently making a worpress theme. And in the loop I want to have two "post-entry" divs one that's small that goes next to my post thumb, and one for without the thumb.

I know that I need to do a

```
<div class="post">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?><div class="post-thumb">   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>  </div>  <div class="post-entry-1">   <? } else { ?><div class="post-entry-2">  <?php } ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for a few days now.

Comment: This would be a great question for StackExchange's new [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) Beta site.

Comment: Hi Chris_O thank you for the comment and advice, I will add it there :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference here are the available Template Tags to place in your LOOP:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

It sounds like you need to use the

the_excerpt(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

And the_content(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Perhaps you need to look over the loop:

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <!-- The following tests if the current post is in category 3. -->
 <!-- If it is, the div box is given the CSS class "post-cat-three". -->
 <!-- Otherwise, the div box will be given the CSS class "post". -->
 <?php if ( in_category('3') ) { ?>
           <div class="post-cat-three">
 <?php } else { ?>
           <div class="post">
 <?php } ?>

 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

 <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

 <!-- Display the Post's Content in a div box. -->
 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>

 <!-- Display a comma separated list of the Post's Categories. -->
 <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
 </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

 <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>

 <!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
 <!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

 <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Todd, yeah I'm using the_excerpt(). I did put it in the post, but it obviously hasn't shown :S

Comment: I edited it to show a loop example that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Todd, I have managed to solve the problem. With help though, it turns out I had an extra which didn't need to be there. Once deleted it was full functioning again. Thank you for your help Todd!