# Help with Wordpress Query

Tags: wordpress, function, loops, themes

I'm sort of a noob when it comes to Wordpess; I've only recently started building themes and I've run into a wall. I'm trying to feature 3 different articles at the top of my site using wpquery and for some reason it's only displaying one. I'll include my code below and if anyone can help my figure out what's wrong I would be very grateful!

Code included in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/1DB7vent

```
<div class="site_width">
  <ul>
     <?php
     $args = array( 'tag' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => '3' );
     $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
     ?>
     <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured', array( 'title'  => '' )); ?>
        </a>
        <label>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
           </a>
        </label>
     </li>
     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the "li" to repeat 2 more times for a total of three. I'm trying to get a setup similar to this:

```
 <div class="site_width">
   <li>
      <a href="feat.article1.permalink" title="feat.article1.title">
         <img src="feat.article1.featured.image">
      </a>
      <label>
         <a href="feat.article1.permalink" title="feat.article1.title">
            "Featured Article 1 Title"
         </a>
      </label>
   </li>
   <REPEAT 'LI' ABOVE TWICE MORE BELOW>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is your loop?

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741399/wordpress-query-posts-adding-two-post-entry-divs-one-with-post-thumbnail-and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382905/wordpress-query-posts-how-to-show-multiple-posts

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in current theme's directory at loop.php. You need to loop through your query results and display them. The general structure is like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
       <?php //show your post  ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
```